# How to convert dynamic Json to specific format of POJO class using Java

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, jackson

**Input Json file looks like below code:**

```
 {
      "Payload": {
        "any0": {
          "pricingResponse": {
            "priceDetails": {
              "priceDetails": {
                "seqId": "8015B000000Umo1QAC-",
                "companyCode": "EPA",
                "priceType": "Fuel Price",
                "priceRequestSource": ""
              },
              "priceLineItems": {
                "lineItem": [
                  {
                    "lineItemInfo": {
                      "seqId": "8015B000000Umo1QAC-28052018105047-022596",
                      "orderId": "00000266",
                      "lineItemId": "44",
                      "itemId": "70051",
                      "quantity": "100.00",
                      "unitPrice": "2.03200",
                      "unitPriceLCY": "2.03200"
                                   }
                    }
                            ]
                    }
                }
             }
           }
         }
      }
```

**Expected output(java class)**

```
 public class Payload 
   {
      public Any0 any0;
   }

    /* Stub Class for Any0 */
   public class Any0 
   {
        public PricingResponse pricingResponse;
   }

    /* Stub Class for PricingResponse */
    public class PricingResponse 
    {
        public PriceDetails priceDetails;
    }

    /* Stub Class for PriceDetails */
    public class PriceDetails 
    {
        public String seqId;
        public String priceRequestSource;
        public String companyCode;
        public String priceType;
        public String deliveryType;
        public String currencyCode;
        public String priceDate;
        public String applyOrderQuantity;
        public String totalOrderQuantity;
        public String customerId;
        public String shipToId;
        public String supplyLocationId;
        public String transporterId;
        public String onRun;
        public String orderId;
        public PriceDetails priceDetails;
        public PriceLineItems priceLineItems;
        public Error Error;
    }

    /* Stub Class for PriceLineItems */
    public class PriceLineItems 
    {
        public String orderId;
        public List<LineItem> lineItem;
    }

    /* Stub Class for LineItem */
    public class LineItem 
    {
        public LineItemInfo lineItemInfo;
        public AccountingDetails accountingDetails;
        public Error Error;
    }
```

I tried to convert it using Jackson Library it's working and creating as the separate POJO classes but I want to create nested class.This is my sample code

```
  public void convert2JSON(URL inputJson, File outputPojoDirectory, String packageName, String className) throws IOException
   {  
          JCodeModel codeModel = new JCodeModel();  
          URL source = inputJson;  
          GenerationConfig config = new DefaultGenerationConfig()
     {  
          @Override  
          public boolean isGenerateBuilders() 
          { // set config option by overriding method  
            return true;  
          }  
          public SourceType getSourceType()
          {  
            return SourceType.JSON;  
          }  

     };  
          SchemaMapper mapper = new SchemaMapper(new RuleFactory(config, new Jackson2Annotator(config), new SchemaStore()), new SchemaGenerator());  
          mapper.generate(codeModel, className, packageName, source);  
          codeModel.build(outputPojoDirectory);  
   }
```

This is the output I am getting 
[image]

Is there a possible way to convert dynamic nested Json class file into Java class? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are Java based Jackson like libraries to marshal and unmarshal JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Map<String, ValueClass>` for every structure that contains variable keys and unvarying values (of type `ValueClass`).

If you'd also like to deserialize maps with variable value structures, you'll need to write a custom deserializer that can infer which Java class should the JSON be deserialized to. [Here's a tutorial for how can you do that with GSON](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-deserialization-basics).